# space between my nav element won't adapt to viewport

Tags: html, css, flexbox

i want the space between my nav elements stretching or shrink depending the viewport , then i use percentage measure for the width of each nav element but it seems it don't work because of the display:flex Here is the code :

```css
    /*CSS*/
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        .topbar{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            padding: 30px;
            background-color: lightgrey;
        }
        
        .topbar nav a{
            display: inline-block;
            width: 15%
        }
        .icon a{
            margin:0px 10px;
        }
    </style>
```

```html
<!-- /*HTML*/-->
    <header  class="topbar">
            <nav>
                <a  href="#">Home</a>
                <a  href="#">about</a>
                <a  href="#">products</a>
                <a  href="#">contact</a>
            </nav>
            <div class="icon">
                <a href="#" >Sign up<i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                <a href="#" >Log in<i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
            </div>
    </header>
    <!-- /header -->
```

So when i remove the `display:flex` and add `display:inline-block` in topbar nav a the space adapt correctly to viewport but i need the flex .

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the `<nav>` element a flex box, with `flex-grow` set to `1` so it fills all of the available space.

```css
    .topbar{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        padding: 0px;
        background-color: lightgrey;
        flex-wrap:wrap;
    }
    
    .topbar nav {
      display:flex;
      flex-grow:1;
       justify-content: space-around;
       position:relative;
    }
    
    .topbar nav a{
        display:inline-block;
        width: 15%;

    }
    .icon a{
        margin:0px 10px;
    }
```

```html
<header  class="topbar">
        <nav>
            <a  href="#">Home</a>
            <a  href="#">about</a>
            <a  href="#">products</a>
            <a  href="#">contact</a>
        </nav>
        <div class="icon">
            <a href="#" >Sign up<i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
            <a href="#" >Log in<i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
        </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when you use `display: flex` on **top nav bar a**, you're making each `a` element use display `flex`. What you could do is add an extra container for your links and use flex on the container. Or if you want to use flex on each `a` element, use `inline-flex`

```
.topbar{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 30px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

.topbar nav a{
    display: inline-flex;
    /*width: 15%;*/
}
.icon a{
    margin:0px 10px;
}
```